# Google Maps, marker postion correct but center not

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to implement a Google maps on a website, but there's one problem that I can't solve, All my markers are correctly placed but the mapOptions.center is not correct, It's almost well placed but the defined center seems to be placed on the left of the map.

As I set the mapOptions.center with the exact same position of my main marker, I don't get why it's not working properly.

As you can see on the screenshot below, this is the default position of the map when I load the page, but it should be centered on the magenta marker.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
  var map;
      lat = [51.032308, 51.033263, 51.033089],
      lng = [4.474540, 4.47114, 4.473013],
      officeLat = lat[0],
      officeLng = lng[0],
      parking1Lat = lat[1],
      parking1Lng = lng[1],
      parking2Lat = lat[2],
      parking2Lng = lng[2];

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
  function init() {
      var customPin = './src/img/custom-map-pin.png'
      var parkingPin = './src/img/custom-map-parking-pin.png'
      var drag;
      var zoomIn;
      var offsettop;
      var offsetleft;
      if(window.innerWidth > 667){
        drag = false
        zoomIn = 17
        offsettop = '100px'
        offsetleft = '220px'
      }else{
        drag = true
        zoomIn = 16
        offsettop = '70px'
        offsetleft = '140px'
  }
  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(officeLat, officeLng),
      zoom: zoomIn,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      draggable: true,


      styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#B0B0B0"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
  };
  var contentString = '<ul class="mapInfo" id="mapInfo">'+
    '<li class="mapInfo--item element">Begijnenkerkhof 6A</li>'+
    '<li class="mapInfo--item element">2800 Mechelen</li>'+
    '<li class="mapInfo--item element">Belgium</li>'+
    '<li class="mapInfo--item element">+32 15 20 37 81</li>'+
  '</ul>';


  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(officeLat, officeLng),
      icon: customPin,
      map: map
  });

  var parking1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(parking1Lat, parking1Lng),
    icon: parkingPin,
    map: map
  });

  var parking2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(parking2Lat, parking2Lng),
    icon: parkingPin,
    map: map
  })

  var infowindow = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
    marker: marker,
    content: contentString,
    wrapperClass: "infoBox",
    offset: {
      top: offsettop,
      left: offsetleft
    },
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    border: false,
    shadow: false,
    closeOnMapClick: false,
    showCloseButton: false

  })
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Any clue on the way to solve that problem ?

Comment: have you taken a look at [this question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4001992/6620283) you seem to be facing similar issues

Comment: Instead of using the map options for the center have you tried before when initializing the map to use the setCenter function? var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, lotitude);
    map.setCenter(latLng);

Comment: @mrdeadsven Yes, I forgot to said that I tried both options but none worked

Comment: @casualcoder haven't found this question before, thanks, It just helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a setTimeout that recenter the map at the end of the init function.
This solution comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42748257/6235358)

```
 setTimeout(function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    var reCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(officeLat, officeLng);
    map.setCenter(reCenter);
 }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add the *fitBounds* option to your map object like:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
map.fitBounds(this.map.bounds);
```

Read more on : [Google Maps Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also tried that before, same result, for now only adding a setTimeout to reload the map once the page is loaded did the trick